# SQL Server 2005 - How can I create a new backup set for a one off back up of a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to create a one off backup of a database that I can then restore on my local machine. I do not want to have any impact on the current media set. I see an option "Back up to new media set, and erase all existing backup sets". What I really want is "Bak up to new media set".